# Change selected option color of bootstrap-select (selectpicker)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the color of the selected option in a `bootstrap-select` to change.. I think this is something real simple, but I tried different things but I can't get it to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select option[selected]{
    background-color: xxx
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the selected options value where the options are words for colours:

```
$("select option:selected").val();
```

To get the selected options background colour:

```
$("select option:selected").css('backgroundColor');
```

**EDIT** per comment:

```
$("select option:selected").css('backgroundColor', '#FFFFFF');
```

Comment: OK, but I want to change the color by CSS. Is that possible?